# Erro ao instalar PHP Cli-Menu

Tags: php, composer

Estava instalando o PHP Cli-menu como indicado na pagina do GitHub:

composer require php-school/cli-menu

Então apareceu esse erro:

Problem 1
    - Installation request for php-school/cli-menu ^2.1 -> satisfiable by php-school/cli-menu[2.1.0].
    - php-school/cli-menu 2.1.0 requires ext-posix * -> the requested PHP extension posix is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: O erro está informando que é necessário ter a extensão `ext-posix` instalada em seu sistema. Verifique no *php.ini* em `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` se a extensão está habilitada.

Comment: Obrigado, sabe informar qual a linha ou trecho do código que mostra se tá habilitado?

Comment: Existe uma sessão nesse arquivo chamada "Dynamic Extensions". Lá você encontrará as extensões mais ou menos assim: `extension=php_mbstring.dll`. Caso esteja com um `;` no início da linha, a extensão está desabilitada. Basta remover o `;`, salvar o arquivo e reiniciar o *server*.